# c# select a value in combobox

Tags: c#, database, select, combobox

My combobox in c# windows forms is filled with data from my database...
Display Members are strings, value members are ints

I now have to preselect it before showing the form.
I have tried:

```
combobox.DisplayMember = string;
combobox.Text = string;
combobox.SelectedItem = string;
combobox.SelectedText = string;
combobox.SelectedValue = string;
```

Anyone that can give me a little help?
Would be much appriciated :-)

EDIT : ei. maybe solution for others...
Remember that the load created by VS2010 designer is loaded after constructor. not within initializeComponents(), as I thought.

Comment: Sorry pal, check it again, if have any problem please drop a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your ComboBox is data-bound and you have properly set up the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties, then you can simply set the SelectedValue property to the value of the item you want to select.

For example, if you had the following objects in your combo box:

```
ID  Description
--  -----------------
2   Lorem
4   Ipsum
6   Dolor
8   Sit
```

You would set the DisplayMember to "Description" and ValueMember to "ID". Then in order to select the item "Dolor", you would just set SelectedValue = 6.

Comment: but i dont have the value only the string :)
And i used visual studio to it, its been good to me so far :-)

Comment: Then look at the FindString method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxyt1t12.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Find the `Item` then set the `SelectedItem` property of combobox to true.

**EDIT:**

```
comboBox.SelectedItem = comboBox.Items.Cast<string>().First(o => o == "blala");
```

use the `Cast<string>()` if your Items is string, Quick Qatching the combobox.Items will show you the object.

In a case that I can't remember exactly whether it was winforms or not, you should set the selected Item's selected property to false, then set another one to true.

check it and if that's the case just add this line:

```
combobox.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: there is no .First under my items, you know why? :-(

Comment: Add System.Linq namespace to usings you have.

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;\n

These are my currents?

Comment: Hehe thanks alot for your answers, they all worked perfectly.(havnt tested after your last edit though).

Comment: +1, I used: `comboBox.SelectedItem = comboBox.Items.Cast<ListItem>().First(o => o.Text == "blala");`

Answer (score 1):

Use `ComboBox.SelectedIndex`.

E.g.:

```
myComboBox.SelectedIndex = [index of item to select];
```

Note that [`ComboBox.Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.items.aspx) is an [`ObjectCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.aspx), which has a method called [`IndexOf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.indexof.aspx). Pass it a reference to the object you want to select, and you should get the proper index back.

Comment: And how should i get the index if i may be so stupid to ask? :-)

Comment: @Anders Metnik Well, one way is to use `ComboBox.Items.IndexOf()`. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
combobox.SelectedIndex = combobox.FindStringExact("myString")
```